# Studio Backup Management: no backup events

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

Using v. 2.2.12 Enterprise.

I'm testing backup functionality with Studio Backup Management as explained in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hU2UkWiDjNM.

Backup is working, I've got backups in specified folder, but not events at all. So I cannot restore.

What's wrong?

[image]

Comment: have you tried refreshing the page?

Comment: Yes. If it may help config/events.json is empty...

Comment: my events.json is empty too, but I see them in the calendar view

Comment: could you eventually add some screenshots?

Comment: Here what I see...no events :(

Comment: you are right. I think there's a bug. Could you please open an issue on github? https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues